# Updating many rows with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$st = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET some_id = ? WHERE id = ?");

foreach ($items as $key => $val)
    $st->execute(array($key, $val));
```

Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: What exactly are you finding to be inefficient about that? Is there an actual issue that you're having or is this premature optimization?

Comment: @PatrickQ No it works just fine, I was just guessing that calling this many times is bad when the application becomes bigger and it needs to update more rows..? But I am actually not sure how these queries work internally tbh, do they execute update queries separately or not..

Comment: Prepare/Execute was designed for this. You prepare a statement, then you run execute for how many times you need it. I do not see anything wrong with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is all about size ;)

If you want to `INSERT` **milions of rows** you should:

1. Generate CSV from php, place it in location available from database.
2. `CREATE TABLE items_copy LIKE items` or similar.
3. Remove all keys from `items_copy`
4. Insert into `items_copy` FROM CSV file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html
5. `UPDATE SET` combined with `SELECT * FROM items_copy`
6. `DROP TABLE items_copy`

If you want to insert just **couple of thousands rows** you should combine your query into one big string and do it in transaction, like:

`$q = 'START TRANSACTION;';
$q .= 'UPDATE items SET some_id = ? WHERE id = ?;';
$q.=  'UPDATE items SET some_id = ? WHERE id = ?;';
....
$q .= 'COMMIT;';`

And then execute `$q`. The reason you should do that is connecting to database for each query will ruin effectiveness.

Otherwise you foreach function will be just fine.

Comment: Good suggestion, when data is too large bulk insert is the most sane way

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm maybe,

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

$dbh->exec('LOCK TABLES items');

$st = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET some_id = ? WHERE id = ?");

foreach ($items as $key => $val)
    $st->execute(array($key, $val)); 

$dbh->commit();
$dbh->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
```